# value of "remember me" spring security

Tags: spring-security

What is the utility of `remember me` to spring security. Is that it is already known by spring security like `j_password` variable  and `j_username`?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Security Remember-Me Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html)

> Remember-me or persistent-login authentication refers to web sites
>   being able to remember the identity of a principal between sessions.
>   This is typically accomplished by sending a cookie to the browser,
>   with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing
>   automated login to take place. Spring Security provides the necessary
>   hooks for these operations to take place, and has two concrete
>   remember-me implementations. One uses hashing to preserve the security
>   of cookie-based tokens and the other uses a database or other
>   persistent storage mechanism to store the generated tokens.

I have nothing to add to that.

Comment: you mean in the future connection when I write my login, the browser knows this user by completing the password automatically

Comment: No, read it again: "sending a cookie to the browser, with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing automated login to take place". It would be huge security risk if the initially entered password would be involved here at all.

Answer (score 0):

The server will send the browser a cookie that will be returned (until it expires). When the server sees a request with that cookie, it doesn't pop up the login page as it would otherwise do automatically with Spring Security.

Comment: this means that when another user wants to connect to the application in the same browser, prohibited or rederige it to another page?

Comment: It doesn't know who is using the computer. So the cookie gets sent back to the same web address. If a user has to log into the computer, they get a different set of cookies, though. If the remember-me cookie comes to the web app, it doesn't even ask for a login. I think you can set how long the cookie lives--days, hours or minutes. Or it can expire when the browser closes.